# Icons lining up vertically and not horizontally

Tags: html

My icons in my footer are not lining up as plannend. On mobile devices they line up as planned, but not on desktop.

```
  <div class="row-fluid" style="padding-top: 2em;">
            <div class="span7" style="float: left;">
              <h4>info<br/> info<br/>info</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="span5" style="float: right;">
              <div class="socialcontainer"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="social_facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/></a> </div>
              <div class="socialcontainer"><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="social_twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/></a></div>
              <div class="socialcontainer"><a href="http://www.instagram.com"><img src="social_instagram.png" alt="Instagram"/></a></div>
            </div>

          </div>
```

Comment: Please add the style sheet too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.socialcontainer{
  float:right;
}
.social1{
  float:left;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.social2{
  float:right;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}


// DELETED SOME LINES ....
```

```html
 <div class="row-fluid" style="padding-top: 2em;">
            <div class="span7" style="float: left;">
              <h4>info<br/> info<br/>info</h4>
            </div>

         <div class="socialcontainer">
              <div class="social1"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="social_facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/></a> </div>
              <div class="social1"><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="social_twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/></a></div>
              <div class="social2"><a href="http://www.instagram.com"><img src="social_instagram.png" alt="Instagram"/></a></div>
            </div>

          </div>
```

You was using class socialcontainer for every div containing the link plus `float: right;`
code on .socialcontainer{

```
.socialcontainer{
  float:right;
}
```

So after that line on your code theres a

```
.social1{
  float:left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.social2{
  float:right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

i removed the width and height to prevent problems,
hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
https:// jsfiddle. net/ hkbok1qr/
```

There's no problem with your code. Please include the CSS. Maybe is the [CSS] causing the issue.

Comment: Still no problem for me jsfiddle.net/sfdm8uox/1/

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention the real problem. The line up should be; Facebook, Twitter, Instagram.

But the result on desktop is Twitter, Instagram and Facebook and on mobile it is fine.